# how to create a vector representing bag of word feature

Tags: python, vector, nlp

I'm very new to programming and I would like to know how to create a vector for a word representing if the word and its neighbors can be found in the bag of word that I have.

hypothetically,my vocabulary is list`['star','moon','sun']`

and I have a text that looks like this

```
['the','sun','is','brighter','than','the','moon','because','the','moon','only','reflects','light','from','the','sun','anyways','I','like','stars','the','best','.']
```

I want to create a vector for each word  [0,0,0] which is an array of zeros, each zero represents the corresponding word in the vocabulary list, and I have a context of one word before and one word after,context vectors for each token in the phrase would be the following:
the`[0,0,1]`(context: the sun)
sun`[0,0,1]`(context: the sun is)
is`[0,0,1]`(context: sun is bright)
...
best`[0,0,0]`(context: the best .)
.`[0,0,0]`(context: best.)

now what I already did is creating a list of tri-grams that looks like this:

```
[('$','the','sun'),('the','sun','is'),('sun','is','bright')...('the','best','.'),'('best','.','$')']
```

I think that this way I could check if in each tuple there exists items in the vocabulary, but I'm not sure how do I move on from here, and if this is the right approach to do this.

I would very much appreciate your help!
Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

So your question reduces to "How do I find the position of a word in a list of words?"  This is the Python `index` function, as in

```
vector = [0, 0, 0]
for pos in range (3):
    word = trigram[pos]
    vector[pos] = word_list.index(word)
```

There are better ways to do this in Python, but this is broken into small steps.  Until you can do this on your own, be very wary of doing more NLP programming.

If you're going to attack an NLP problem, I strongly suggest that you take some time to learn programming *first*, independent of your project.  Search on line for a Python tutorial, learn to use the documentation, and gradually learn the terms you'll need for searches in this domain.